# Using a generic class to access other methods from other classes

Tags: java, generics

Lets say I have 6 or more specific classes that have unique variables for each class but the same methods throughout. How can I use my generic class to access the method of the specific class? Is that even possible or do I have to do another approach?

```
//Specific Class
package test;
public class Specific<T> {
    String name = "John";
    int age = 18;

    public void specificDetails() {
        System.out.println("Myname is " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old.");
    }
}

//generic class
import test.Specific;

public class Generic {
    public static <E> void printPersonDetails(E person) {
        //this is the problem. How can I access this method using generics?
        person.specificDetails;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Specific specificPerson = new Specific();
        printPersonDetails(specificPerson);
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The obvious answer is to make all the classes implement an interface that defines the method you're referring to.

Comment: Actually I don't see the point of using generics in your example. You could simply have an abstract class (e.g. `Person` class) with abstract method `specificDetails()`, and subclass just have to override the method with actual data, then you can just call the base class method with any reference of `Person` subclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler that `E` is related to `Specific<T>`. Something like,

```
public static <E extends Specific<?>> void printPersonDetails(E person) {
    person.specificDetails();
}
```